# Sapui5 Flexbox layout - GridList BasicLayout

Tags: xml, flexbox, responsive-design, sapui5, height

### I'm trying to make a Flexible layout for a specific View.

Rather simply, I'd like my view to be split vertically in such a way that the leading element would only take the relevant space for its display (Here, an objectHeader) and the second element would fill the remaining space (A GridList).

I'd like to achieve this using declarative views (no controller code).
I used a FlexBox element for my design and somehow managed to achieve that design, but for a reason I can't explain, the second element, which fills the remaining space, does not make its content fill the space, only the container does.

### As an example :

In the following code, the element with id "trolleyBinsList" has a layout "trolleyBinListLayout". The layout correctly fills the remaining space while the "trolleyBinsList" doesn't :/

I tried playing with the "trolleyBinListLayout" and the "trolleyBinListContentLayout" element but without success.

Here's the content of my Page element:

```
        <content>
            <FlexBox
            id="mainLayout"
            direction="Column"
            fitContainer="true"
            alignItems="Stretch"
            justifyContent="Start"
            >
                <core:Fragment
                fragmentName="...ArticleHeader"
                type="XML"
                />

                <f:GridList
                id="trolleyBinsList"
                headerText="Trolley"
                items="{Bins}"
                includeItemInSelection="true"
                keyboardMode="Navigation"
                mode="None"
                >
                    <f:layoutData>
                        <FlexItemData
                        id="trolleyBinListLayout"
                        growFactor="1"
                        shrinkFactor="0"
                        />
                    </f:layoutData>

                    <f:customLayout>
                        <grid:GridBasicLayout
                        id="trolleyBinListContentLayout"
                        gridTemplateRows="repeat(10, 1fr)"
                        gridTemplateColumns="repeat(4, 1fr)"
                        gridGap="1rem" />
                    </f:customLayout>

                    <f:items>
                        <f:GridListItem
                        id="trolleyBinItem"
                        press="..."
                        >
                        </f:GridListItem>
                    </f:items>

                </f:GridList>
            </FlexBox>
        </content>
```

In case this can impact the design in any way, The grid should have 10 rows and 4 columns, and each cell with identical dimensions, but I need the cells to adapt their height to the available height, not shrink to the min-content height.

Also, I managed to achieve my design by explicitly setting the height of some *rendered* elements to 100%, but I'd like to avoid custom CSS as I read this could lead to future undesired maintenance.

I'm working with **sapui5 version 1.112.1**

**Edit 1 :**
I tryed the FixFlex suggestion and got the same result, which makes me think the issue may be related to the GridLayout rather than it's container layout (FlexBox/FixFlex) ?

Here's a screenshot of the container layout :

[image: Container layout]

And here's a screenshot of the GridList :

[image: GridList layout]

**Edit 2:**
For now, I managed to solve my issue adding a simple css style. I'm just afraid the generated sapui5 HTML for the GridList might change in the future.

**CSS:**

```
.sapFGridList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.sapFGridList header {
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.sapFGridList ul {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

**So as a recap:**

1. My first issue involved the ability to make an element fill my page "content" section using the available space which I solved using a custom css class that sets the height to 100%.
2. My second issue involved the ability for a `Gridlist` element AND it's content to fill it's container (here, the flex section of the `FixFlex`).

Here's a screenshot of the GridList `ul` child after applying my custom css.

[image: GridList filling available space]

I also swapped from `Page` element to `DynamicPage` element to allow the easy header collapse, but this change is not linked to my issue and should not impact it in any way.

Hope that's clear ;)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `trolleyBinsList` having to have 100% in height? The height of the list will grow automatically depending on the number of items.

Comment: Is the grid list supposed to render always 4 items per row, even one a mobile device?

Comment: Indeed It is, even though the main device will be a tablet.

Comment: The number of rows and columns are finite. They represent physical spaces that can, or not, be filled with items. The idea is to take profit of the maximum space available.